# Incompatibilty between siuintx and linguex?

Tags: packages, siunitx, incompatibility, linguistics, linguex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
Foo
\end{document}
```

This MWE produces a plethora of error messages, regardless of the order in which those two packages are loaded. It starts out with:

```
! Use of \fg doesn't match its definition.
\exp_not:V ...numeral:D \__exp_eval_register:N #1}

l.4 \begin{document}

! Argument of \@firstofone has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 \end{document}

! Paragraph ended before \@firstofone was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.6 \end{document}
```

And then many of these follow:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.18 \DeclareSIUnit
                    \A  {        \ampere }
```

While this eventually looks like something that needs to be fixed in one of these packages, I would be grateful for a temporary fix.

I'm using an up-to-date MiKTeX 2.9, but compiling the MWE on [writeLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/19360pdldcb) produces errors as well, and I think that tool uses TeX Live.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`linguex` defines a command `\bg.` to introduce glosses.  It also creates aliases to this command `\cg.`, `\dg.`, `\eg.` and `\fg.`. The `\fg.` command conflicts with `SIUnitx`, which defines `\fg` as femtogram.  The simple solution is to load `linguex` and then redefine `\fg.` to nothing, and then load `siunitx`.  Since the `\fg.` command isn't necessary in `linguex` (and isn't even really documented), it's an easily worked around problem, and not really a bug, since both are end user commands.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{linguex}
\def\fg{}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
Foo
\end{document}
```